# Formatting hover text in Plotly Express vertically

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I’m attemping to display a list of values in the hovertemplate in plotly express

I have the list saved as a single string. It’s made up of 10-20 substrings broken up by commas

The default is for the list to displayed horizontally which doesn’t look best on a map.

Is there a workaround for this to be displayed vertically.

value is something like

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

and is displayed as:

```
list = 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'
```

[image]

I’d like it to be displayed as:

```
a,
b,
c,
d,
e,
f
```

e.g. like this image here, but with the values rotated and readable

[image]

I could map each element to a new value,and have a vertical list of values but the lists are different lengths, I run into the issue of having emtyp values appear as {%cutomdata}.

Comment: did yo tried to replace `,` with `\n` or with `<br>` ?

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I added images but if it's not clear I can create an example in plot.ly